# Create new variable according to time frame/row length and time period classification

Tags: r

I'm new to the forum and R. I'm struggling with this problem. 
I have the following data frame.

```
Date        |   ONIstatus  
01/10/1993  |Average  
01/11/1993  |Average  
01/12/1993  |Average    
01/02/1993  |Average    
01/03/1993  |High    
01/04/1993  |High  
01/05/1993  |High  
01/06/1993  |High  
01/10/1995  |Low  
01/11/1995  |Low  
01/12/1995  |Low
```

I need to create a new variable which categorizes certain events based on the length of an event.   So, If i have 3 consecutive months with a 'high' status,  then i create class in the new variable called 'el ninio event', 3 consecutive low events get classed as a 'la ninia'.  Anything else gets called 'normal' e.g. only one 'High' month.

Every time there is a change in the ONI status, would mark a start of an event.
Would i achieve this using a loop or could i do something with lubridate, Dyply(mutate) and some ifelse statements ?

Thanks

Comment: You said "el ninio event" is "3 consecutive months with a 'high'". So would this be something like every day of July - September (92 days) having the `ONIstatus` of `High`?

Comment: Hi yes exactly, it could be measure in days, months. Or since each row represents a month it could even be done with number of rows >= 3. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following.

```
r <- rle(data$ONIstatus)
r$values[r$lengths < 3] <- 'normal'
r$values[r$values == "High" & r$lengths >= 3] <- 'el ninio event'
r$values[r$values == "Low" & r$lengths >= 3] <- 'la ninia'
data$New <- inverse.rle(r)
data
```

The trick is to use function `rle` to get the lengths of runs values in column `ONIstatus`. Then set the values of `r$values` and reverse the operation.
I didn't know what to call the new column so I called it `New`, change this if you want.

Comment: Great, that worked a treat. Thanks a lot for that, i'm very grateful!